# What is the state of native SVG support in the most popular browsers?

Tags: svg, w3c, web-standards

What is the state of native SVG support in the most popular browsers in their latest releases?

- Internet explorer
- Firefox
- Opera
- Safari
- Chrome
- Konqueror
- Camino

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- IE has SVG support in IE9 but not in IE8 and below. The alternative is [VML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250524.aspx)
- [Mozilla claims to support it on its latest version](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/svg/)
- [Opera claims to support it since v8.0](http://www.opera.com/products/desktop/svg/)
- [Safari has experimental support (probably incomplete)](http://webkit.org/projects/svg/index.html)
- [Chrome seems to have roughly the same level of SVG support as Safari](http://www.nabble.com/Google-Chrome---SVG-support--td19268298.html)
- [Konqueror uses the same SVG engine as Safari and Chrome](http://svg.kde.org/) - KSVG claims to be in beta. The fact that they have a [TODO list](http://svg.kde.org/tasks.php) implies it's not ready for production
- [Camino apparently supports SVG as well](http://svg.org/story/2005/12/30/231328/85)

Comment: Nope. I added a link to an article on theregister.co.uk talking about IE8 features. If you don't feel like reading the whole thing, the note about SVG support is on the 5th paragraph

Comment: If it's not in the beta you can safely assume it's not going to be rolled out.  Most people use Adobe's SVG plugin for IE, but it's not as integrated with the DOM as the others are.

Comment: That list is pretty bad. Mozilla, Opera, Safari have supported SVG for many years and "claims" is not the right word. See pornet's excellent link to a SVG working group co-chair member below.

Answer (score 16):

[Results of testing against W3C SVG Test Suite in various implementations](http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php).

This chart is quite up-to-date and gives a good idea how browsers and browser plugins support SVG.

Answer (score 3):

- Opera has native [SVG support](http://www.opera.com/products/desktop/svg/)
- Firefox has native [SVG support](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/svg/)
- Internet Explorer does NOT include
  [SVG support](http://wiki.svg.org/Internet_Explorer) natively.
- Safari has native [SVG support](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25197?viewlocale=en_US) for images and Fonts since version 3.1.
- Camino contains native [SVG support](http://caminobrowser.org/documentation/setup/) as per its own documentation
- Chrome uses an old version of Web Kit to support [SVG natively](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2008/09/chrome.html)
- Konqueror has SVG support via a plugin [KSVG2](http://svg.kde.org/)

From 2007 a [here](http://www.maa.org/joma/Volume7/Lane/Browser.html) is a list of the state of SVG support in many browsers

Answer (score 3):

## UP-TO-DATE ANSWERS

All of the answers given here are horribly out-of-date<sup>1</sup>. (See footnote 1!)

***For up-to-date information on SVG support see [SVG section of caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG).***

---

#### Footnotes

1. That's not meant as a complaint, as no one can expect answers from 2008 to still be relevant in 2013 (or `Time.now`, for that matter).  I'm just alerting readers of this page to the fact of the answers' staleness, not in any way trying to criticize answers that were once useful and timely.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that not only does IE natively lack support but the major plugin (from Adobe) was end of lifed. While many of the browsers above offser support it is highly, highly uneven.